# Attenuation curve of the twisted pair cable

Tags: cables, crosstalk

I'm searching an image of attenuation of twisted pair **utp** and **stp** for school report. I googled and I found only utp [this](http://www.google.com/imgres?um=1&hl=en&sa=N&biw=1674&bih=852&tbm=isch&tbnid=clCq6ZdTikXErM:&imgrefurl=http://www.extron.com/company/article.aspx?id=dvihdmitwistedpair_ts&docid=rrGhHYFJxxBI9M&imgurl=http://www.extron.com/company/img/figure1.jpg&w=322&h=245&ei=UCyqT5T7DZDU4QTr2uSLCQ&zoom=1&iact=hc&vpx=189&vpy=320&dur=1624&hovh=196&hovw=257&tx=182&ty=105&sig=114433099336668277535&page=1&tbnh=148&tbnw=195&start=0&ndsp=30&ved=1t:429,r:7,s:0,i:90) curve!

[image]

any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your UTP curve is only qualitative, i.e. doesn't show actual numbers. Your STP cable will show similar behavior: attenuation increases with distance, and so does crosstalk. The shielding won't prevent that. The qualitative image will look the same.

Quantitatively, expect the STP to have a higher attenuation due to capacitive coupling with the shielding's ground.

Comment: I would expect that  shield **may** alter the nature of the multisection distributed LC filter which the line "models" so that the attenuation level and/or curve shape with distance would alter. But, if so, the difference will be small.

Comment: @Russell - Impossible to say without the spec of the actual cable. I don't expect a big difference either, but intuitively if there's any it should be worse for the STP.

Comment: My college had cable ducts in the walls with plenty of UTP cables that suffered from crosstalk. When somebody complained that the network was failing, the janitor would go and ruffle the cables with a broom. That would decrease the coupling and fix it for a while.